# Куда вставлять код SASS?

Tags: css, sass

Я пока не знаком с технологией SASS, понимаю только что это какое-то расширение CSS, но чем она поддерживается, браузерами или сервером, не понимаю.

Собственно вопрос: в документации к библиотеке Foundation рекомендуется менять размер шрифта при помощи следующих директив:

```
// We use these to control header font sizes
$h1-font-size: rem-calc(44);
$h2-font-size: rem-calc(37);
$h3-font-size: rem-calc(27);
$h4-font-size: rem-calc(23);
$h5-font-size: rem-calc(18);
$h6-font-size: 1rem;
```

Но куда их вставлять? Нужна для этого какая-то библиотека, установленная на сервере или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы почитайте http://sass-lang.com/
Sass — это компилируемый язык. Браузеры всё равно понимают только чистый css.
Что вы прочитали, там речь вот о чём:
нужно установить zurb foundation из исходников, отсюда: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/ , и при сборке проекта компилировать его в css.
В файле scss/foundation/_settings.scss вы найдёте закомментированные строки с названными переменными. Их нужно установить в нужные вам значения, и после этого перекомпилировать.

Если мои слова звучат как тарабарщина, то нужно просто подключить библиотеку, а следом подключить свой файл css, и в нём назначить собственные размеры шрифтов для заголовков.

Comment: Спасибо, нет не тарабарщина, я все понял. Просто думал что эти строки просто куда-то вставляются без какой-то компиляции, и что это будет проще, чем прописывать размеры шрифта заголовков через css для каждого размера экрана (собственно в этом и задача, заголовки огромные, нужно их все уменьшить на определенный процент). Но теперь понял, что ну его, проще обычным css орудовать.

Comment: вообще, это только по первости кажется, что проще обычным css.
Нужно некоторое небольшое усилие, чтобы понять, вникнуть и принять новые технологии. Но это усилие реально небольшое. Скорее даже вопрос привычки. Но может понравиться и вызвать привыкание.
Компиляция — не такая страшная штука. К тому, что можно наладить вотчер, чтобы стили компилировались автоматом при изменении файлов scss. Но все эти прелести в виде переменных, миксинов, функций — они изучаются довольно быстро и легко, документация вся есть, а упрощают работу существенно.

Comment: Да, я думаю вы правы :) Надо изучать!